# KubernetesPodOperator shows completed in Airflow UI but keep on running in backend

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer, kubernetespodoperator

I am working on KubernetesPodOperator for one of the development.
In that, I have used this to generate the files in GCP.
I tried the below approach and it was working fine too.
The KubernetesPodOperator task shows completed(green) in Airflow UI interface, but looks like it is keep on running in the backend.

Can someone help me on this to fix this continuous generation of files.

Is there anyway to kill the running kubernetescluster or pod if any.
Or is there any other way/parameter needs to be added to run the task with KubernetesPodOperator

I tried multiple approaches but the log show, Deleting Pod at the completion of the task

Comment: sample code which we have used
kb_file = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace= ** related to the project **,
   image = ** (mentioned the relevant project one's) **,
   cmds=['echo','10'],
   arguments= ** passed one of the airflow task here **,
   labels={"foo": "bar"},
   name="file_test",
   task_id="file_test",
   get_logs=True,
   config_file= ** config file path **,
   dag=dag,
   kubernetes_conn_id = ** connection id **,
   is_delete_operator_pod=True,
   )

Comment: have you tried the below option suggested by docs https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/operators.html#kubernetespodoperator :

on_finish_action="delete_pod",

Comment: Please don't add comments to clarify. Code is unreadable in comments. [Edit] your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the `is_delete_operator_pod=True` is deprecated, use on_finish_action="delete_pod"

pls see comments in this file:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/pod.py

or in

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/operators.html#kubernetespodoperator

Comment: yes .. tried that, the log shows deleting pod, but still the files are getting generated

and also getting the below error in the log
{pod_manager.py:529} ERROR - Error parsing timestamp (no timestamp in message ''). Will continue execution but won't update timestamp